# rolling average in case of missing month in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, moving-average

I have data in this format

```
student_id,month1,fees
A1,201612,22
A1,201611,33
A1,201610,44
A1,201609,55
A1,201608,66
A1,201607,77
A1,201606,88
A2,201612,12
A2,201610,24
A2,201609,36
A2,201607,48
```

I want fees of every student considering average of last three month fees means for student A1, for month 201612, fees will be sum(22,33,44)/3 so I used this query

```
(select student_id,month1,fees,(sum(fees) over(partition by
student_id
order by
student_id
,
month1
asc rows between 2 preceding and current row ))/3 as avg1 from table where
month1
>(select trim(Add_Months(cast(trim(maxrepmonth) as DATE Format 'YYYYMM'),-5) (format 'YYYYMM')) from (select max(
month1
) as maxrepmonth from table) z2)  group by 1,2,3)
```

and this works fine for student A1 as it is having all months data but in case of student A2, for month 201612, It is taking fees from these months 201612,201610,201609 which is wrong, instead it should take only from 201612,201610 as 201611 is missing.
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Well, Teradata not supporting the RANGE window clause was a surprise to me. Should read the docu first ...  But I just posted a possible workaround a minute ago

Answer (score 0):

OLAP functions from the ANSI-99 standard are your friend here - especially the RANGE window clause.

Try this - I'm doing it with Vertica, but Teradata should be just as ANSI compliant and do it for you, too:

```
    WITH foo(student_id,month1,fees) AS (
                        SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-12-01',22
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-11-01',33 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-10-01',44 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-09-01',55 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-08-01',66 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-07-01',77 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-06-01',88 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A2',DATE '2016-12-01',12 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A2',DATE '2016-10-01',24 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A2',DATE '2016-09-01',36 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A2',DATE '2016-07-01',48
    )
    SELECT
        *
    , AVG(fees) OVER (
            PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY month1
            RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '3 MONTHS' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS rolling_avg_3_months
    FROM foo;

student_id|month1    |fees|rolling_avg_3_months
A1        |2016-06-01|  88|                  88
A1        |2016-07-01|  77|                82.5
A1        |2016-08-01|  66|                  77
A1        |2016-09-01|  55|                  66
A1        |2016-10-01|  44|                  55
A1        |2016-11-01|  33|                  44
A1        |2016-12-01|  22|                  33
A2        |2016-07-01|  48|                  48
A2        |2016-09-01|  36|                  42
A2        |2016-10-01|  24|                  30
A2        |2016-12-01|  12|                  18
```

Comment: Teradata does not support RANGE

Comment: Hi, It is giving error "expected the word reset or ')' after order by clause" It is not supporting range interval in teradata.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dudu, thanks Amit

So Teradata does not support RANGE ...

Now it becomes trickier.

Found a working solution, but it needs some explanation.

Hope the comments are enough.

```
WITH 
-- the input data
     foo(student_id,month1,fees) AS (
          SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-12-01',22
UNION ALL SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-11-01',33 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-10-01',44 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-09-01',55 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-08-01',66 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-07-01',77 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-06-01',88 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A2',DATE '2016-12-01',12 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A2',DATE '2016-10-01',24 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A2',DATE '2016-09-01',36 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A2',DATE '2016-07-01',48
)
-- add two columns fees1before and fees2before, that can be null,
-- containing the fees of the two previous rows if the 'month1' 
-- value of those rows is less than 3 months back
,    foo_3_months AS (
SELECT
  student_id
, month1
, fees  AS fees_now
, CASE 
    WHEN 
      MONTHS_BETWEEN(month1,LAG(month1) OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY month1))
    < 3
    THEN LAG(fees) OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY month1)
   END AS fees_1before
, CASE 
    WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(month1,LAG(month1,2) OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY month1))
    < 3
    THEN LAG(fees,2) OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY month1)
   END AS fees_2before
  FROM foo
)
-- finally, build a hard-wired average formula that takes care of
-- the fact that two of the three values can be NULL
-- I'm keeping the two additional columns for debugging purposes.
-- They can be removed in the end.
SELECT 
  *
, (fees_now+NVL(fees_1before,0)+NVL(fees_2before,0) )
/ (
    1
  + (CASE WHEN fees_1before IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  + (CASE WHEN fees_2before IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  )
AS rolling_avg_3months
FROM foo_3_months
;
```

Here's the result:

```
student_id|month1    |fees_now|fees_1before|fees_2before|rolling_avg_3months
A1        |2016-06-01|      88|-           |-           |88.000000000000000000
A1        |2016-07-01|      77|          88|-           |82.500000000000000000
A1        |2016-08-01|      66|          77|          88|77.000000000000000000
A1        |2016-09-01|      55|          66|          77|66.000000000000000000
A1        |2016-10-01|      44|          55|          66|55.000000000000000000
A1        |2016-11-01|      33|          44|          55|44.000000000000000000
A1        |2016-12-01|      22|          33|          44|33.000000000000000000
A2        |2016-07-01|      48|-           |-           |48.000000000000000000
A2        |2016-09-01|      36|          48|-           |42.000000000000000000
A2        |2016-10-01|      24|          36|-           |30.000000000000000000
A2        |2016-12-01|      12|          24|-           |18.000000000000000000
```

Not an easy task - and maybe a Request for Enhancement to Teradata?

Happy playing - 
Marco the Sane

Answer (score 0):

I just finished a second way of dealing with your need. Took me two hours, though, and I had to find the time to do that. But I was curious myself, so it's not wasted time.

The advantage of this approach is that it is more flexible. It's easier to change if you need 4, 5 or 6 months instead of 3, and you don't have to cater for the possibility of components to be NULL, because you can use the normal AVG() OVER().

The downside is a much more complex data preparation phase: You have to fill gaps, containing NULLs for the measure, and create a list of all possible firsts of month between the smallest `month1` and the greatest `month1`  values in the base table. For this purpose, I mimick the TIMESERIES clause from Vertica.

The solution contains a lot that I think will be handy in the survival kit of anybody digging deeper into SQL, like creating in-line tables of consecutive integers, and time series out of these. That's also why I create a series of 100 integers when 7 would be enough. It also shows that a CROSS JOIN is not always a disaster.

I tried to sufficiently comment what I'm doing here, I hope it's enough.

```
-- WITHOUT RANGE BETWEEN - vertical version
WITH 
-- the input data
     foo(student_id,month1,fees) AS (
          SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-12-01',22
UNION ALL SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-11-01',33 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-10-01',44 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-09-01',55 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-08-01',66 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-07-01',77 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A1',DATE '2016-06-01',88 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A2',DATE '2016-12-01',12 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A2',DATE '2016-10-01',24 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A2',DATE '2016-09-01',36 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A2',DATE '2016-07-01',48
)
-- 1. Mimick Vertica's TIMESERIES clause:
--    Prepare a series of month-start dates
--    from the first month to the last month
--    of the time series. Assuming it's more than
--    10 months:
--  1.a  A series of 100 ints starting from 0
--  1.a.1 start with 10 ints
,    ten_ints(idx) AS (
          SELECT 0
UNION ALL SELECT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 2
UNION ALL SELECT 3
UNION ALL SELECT 4
UNION ALL SELECT 5
UNION ALL SELECT 6
UNION ALL SELECT 7
UNION ALL SELECT 8
UNION ALL SELECT 9
)
-- 1.a.2 make 100 out of 10
,    idx_series AS (
SELECT
  tens.idx * 10 + units.idx AS idx
FROM ten_ints units
CROSS JOIN ten_ints tens
)
-- 1.b get limit dates and total month count
,    month_limits AS (
SELECT
  MIN(month1) AS start_month
, MAX(month1) AS end_month
, MONTHS_BETWEEN(MAX(month1), MIN(month1)) AS monthcount
FROM foo
)
-- 1.c create an artificial list of all student_id
--     and all possible months to fill gaps
--     This is the end of the TIMESERIES mimick.
,    student_month_list AS (
SELECT
  student_id
, ADD_MONTHS(start_month,idx) AS month1
FROM month_limits
JOIN idx_series
  ON idx <= monthcount
CROSS 
  JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT student_id FROM foo
  ) bar
)
-- This returns:
-- student_id|month1
-- A1        |2016-06-01
-- A1        |2016-07-01
-- A1        |2016-08-01
-- A1        |2016-09-01
-- A1        |2016-10-01
-- A1        |2016-11-01
-- A1        |2016-12-01
-- A2        |2016-06-01
-- A2        |2016-07-01
-- A2        |2016-08-01
-- A2        |2016-09-01
-- A2        |2016-10-01
-- A2        |2016-11-01
-- A2        |2016-12-01

-- Main query: 
-- left join student_month_list to the base table
-- and filter out the rows whose measure is NULL
SELECT 
  mth.student_id
, mth.month1
, AVG(foo.fees) OVER (
  PARTITION BY mth.student_id ORDER BY mth.month1
  ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
) AS running_avg_3months
FROM student_month_list mth
LEFT JOIN foo USING(student_id, month1)
WHERE foo.fees IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1,2
;
```